# Custom object with dependencies in CMake

Tags: cmake, simulink, custom-object, build-dependencies

I am contributing a custom feature--say, **MyFeature**--to a project that uses CMake and has separate source and build directories.  **MyFeature** consists of a single binary file.  (**MyFeature** is in fact a custom Simulink library, so I have to invoke MATLAB to create it--the important thing here is that creating the object does not involve GCC or the other standard build tools that CMake uses by default.)  So I have a special rule to build the object--let's say **myRule**.  I want **make** to run **myRule** only if  (a) **MyFeature** does not exist, or (b) the one source file on which **MyFeature** depends--say, **MySource**--is newer than the currently-existing **MyFeature**.  A small added wrinkle is that I only really need **MyFeature** in the source tree, which is where **myRule** normally places it.  How can I accomplish all this?

I cannot use either **add_executable** or **add_library**, as far as I can tell, because they are designed narrowly for objects that you build using the GCC (or otherwise already-configured) toolchain.  I cannot use **add_custom_target**, because the resulting target is *always* out of date.  So far, I have made some progress using a combination of **add_custom_target** and **add_custom_command**, as follows:

```
add_custom_target(fakeTarget
    DEPENDS MyFeature)

add_custom_command(OUTPUT MyFeature
    COMMAND myRule && touch ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/MyFeature
    DEPENDS mySource)

add_dependencies(targetThatAlwaysRuns fakeTarget)
```

The command to create an empty **MyFeature** file in the build tree seems sufficient to fake **make** into not rebuilding if the real **MyFeature** exists (in the source tree), which accomplishes one of my goals.  However, once this fake file exists, even if I update **MySource** in the source tree, **make** does not rebuild **MyFeature**.  This is where I am stuck.  It seems especially puzzling because I can see in the **CMakeFiles** innards that there is a target for **MyFeature** that does indeed list **MySource** (with the correct path--in the source tree!) as a dependency.  If I were to try to replicate this situation with a much simpler (toy) Makefile in a single directory, if I update one of the source files on which the target depends, even if the target output file already exists, **make** will do the right thing--it will rebuild the object from the updated source and then rebuild the overall target.  So why is the build behavior in this situation different?  And what can I do to accomplish goal (b) along with goal (a)?  Thanks!

Comment: Assuming by `add_custom_rule` you mean `add_custom_command`, this your approach should work. Try to use absolute paths in *DEPENDS* and *OUTPUT* options. "A small added wrinkle is that I only really need MyFeature in the source tree" - nothing prevents you to create file in the source tree.

Comment: Oops!  Yes, I meant add_custom_command--have edited to fix this.  True, nothing prevents me from creating a file in the source tree; I was explaining the reason for my hack of putting an empty file into the build tree.  CMake _does_ prevent me from defining a target in the source tree, so, therefore, the output file in add_custom_command also cannot be in the source tree.

Comment: Adding the absolute path to the *DEPENDS* option in add_custom_command worked!  Thank you!

Comment: Now the question is how I can avoid the hack of writing the dummy **MyFeature** file to the build tree in order to have **Make** skip the build rule if the real **MyFeature** exists.  The problem with this hack is that it does not work if, say, the user deletes the real **MyFeature** in the source tree:  so long as the fake **MyFeature** is still in the build tree, **Make** will not regenerate **MyFeature**.

Comment: I don't quite understand: If you need `MyFeature` to be generated in *source tree*, why do you create it in *binary tree*? OUTPUT of `add_custom_command` can be in the source tree as well, just use absolute paths.

Answer (score 0):

As Tsyvarev suggested in his comment, all I had to do was to specify the *DEPENDS* dependency with an absolute path:

```
add_custom_target(fakeTarget
    DEPENDS MyFeature)

add_custom_command(OUTPUT MyFeature
    COMMAND myRule && touch ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/MyFeature
    DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/mySource)

add_dependencies(targetThatAlwaysRuns fakeTarget)
```

However, now suppose a user deletes the real **MyFeature** from the source tree and then runs **Make** again.  **Make** will not regenerate **MyFeature**, because the fake **MyFeature** is still present in the build tree.  How can I overcome this problem?